# Missing Database Table Aro (expected "aros"), create it first

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp

I have an application that uses Cake PHP and it does not want to run properly. I am getting numerous errors and do not even know where to start fixing it:

> Notice: Undefined variable: permissions in
>   app/views/layouts/default.thtml on line 58 Call Stack: 0.0000 637384
>
> 1. {main}() /app/webroot/index.php:0 0.0022 892856
> 2. Dispatcher->dispatch() /app/webroot/index.php:84 0.0051 1104112
> 3. Controller->_initComponents() /cake/dispatcher.php:227 0.0051 1104616
> 4. Component->init() /cake/libs/controller/controller.php:271 0.0051 1105304
> 5. Component->__loadComponents() /cake/libs/controller/component.php:59 0.0054 1116768
> 6. AclComponent->__construct() /cake/libs/controller/component.php:124 0.0054 1116768
> 7. AclComponent->getACL() /cake/libs/controller/components/acl.php:56 0.0074 1543960
> 8. Model->__construct() /cake/libs/controller/components/acl.php:72 0.0097 1855456
> 9. Model->setSource() /cake/libs/model/model_php5.php:301 0.0103 1856912
> 10. Object->cakeError() /cake/libs/model/model_php5.php:518 0.0106 1885784
> 11. ErrorHandler->__construct() /cake/libs/object.php:169 0.0111 1892840

At the bottom it says:

> Missing Database Table No Database table for model Aro (expected
>   "aros"), create it first. Notice: If you want to customize this error
>   message, create app/views/errors/missing_table.html.

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong?

Comment: Did you try setting up ACL tables via cake bake (cake acl initdb)?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a database table

It's looking for the table "aros" but can't find it.  Create the table based on the ACL part of the CakePHP book.